# Trying to format the h3 element in a table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried to recreate the issue that I am having in JSFiddle. The h3 element EEE-EEE EEEEEEEEE EEE EEEE is stacked on each other when the browser is full size on a computer. When it is maximized the h3 element expands to be on one line. I would like to have this element on one line at all times. Does anyone know a way to do this? https://jsfiddle.net/886xfe6d/

```
<tr>
    <td>
          <h3>EEE-EEE EEEEEEEEE EEE EEEE</h3>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
td h3 {white-space: nowrap}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp

Comment: This works but it formats the incident header below it to the length of the h3 element. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: Oh, sure. You should just set `<td colspan="12">` on the cell with the `<h3>` caption so it could… well, span for whole 12 columns ;)

Comment: (p.s. don't forget to consider accepting the answer if it has helped in solving your issue)